# Solve trigonometric equation involving exponents

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following equation on $\mathbb{N}^*$:
$$2^n\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} = 8$$

I tried to solve it by trying to plug in different values for $n$, but I haven't found anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about the $8?$ For $n=3,4$ you get $-8.$

Comment: Yes, it's $8$, not $-8$.

Comment: You sure we aren't supposed to consider $2n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: I don't think the equation has a solution. With $\;-8\;$ on the right side it would have, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\lvert\cos(n\pi/3)\rvert\in\{1,1/2\}$, so
$$
\left|2^n\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}\right|\in\{2^n,2^{n-1}\}
$$
This leaves only the cases $n=3$ or $n=4$ that you can inspect directly.

Comment: I guess the downvoter doesn't understand the absolute value. What a pity.

Answer (score 3):

We can approach this as follows:

$$\cos\frac{n\pi}3=\begin{cases}1,&n=0\pmod6\\{}\\\cfrac12,&n=1,2\pmod 6\\{}\\-1,&n=3\pmod 6\\{}{}\\-\cfrac12,&n=4,5\pmod6\end{cases}$$

Doing case by case, you can see that there is no solution, since for example

$$2^7\cos\frac{7\pi}3=2^7\frac12=2^6>8$$

and thus only the first cases are worth taking into consideration...and they aren't solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^n>0$, we should find $n$ values that make $\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})$ positive. Also note that since $2\pi=\frac{6\pi}{3}$, any acceptable $n$ in $[0,2\pi]$ will result in $n+6$ being acceptable too. Looking in the range $[0,2\pi]$ we can see $\color{red}{n=0,1,5,6}$ make $\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})$ positive and equal to $1,2^{-1},2^{-1},1$ respectively.

Now check the two cases considering the exponential part:

- $n=1,5:$ $$2^n(2^{-1})=2^3\Rightarrow n=4$$
  which is a conflict.
- $n=0,6:$ 
  $$2^n(1)=2^3\Rightarrow n=3$$
  again is conflict.

Higher values: $\cos$ remains fixed and the exponential increases, while we need $3$ on the RHS. So there is no solution.